# How can return an external method as an option?

Tags: reason-react

I'm trying to create a module for XMLHttpRequest that I can call in `Reason.useEffect`.  The code below I've tried in a single instance and seems to work, but I'd like to be able to hand `Reason.useEffect` the ability to call the library's "abort": right now I'm giving it `None` so `React` doesn't do anything if there's a problem.

```
type request;
type response;
[@bs.new] external makeXMLHttpRequest: unit => request = "XMLHttpRequest";
[@bs.send] external addEventListener: (request, string, unit => unit) => unit = "addEventListener";
[@bs.get] external response: request => response = "response";
[@bs.send] external open_: (request, string, string) => unit = "open";
[@bs.send] external setRequestHeader: (request, string) => unit ="setRequestHeader";
[@bs.send] external send: request => unit = "send";
[@bs.send] external abort: request => unit = "abort";

[@bs.scope "JSON"][@bs.val] external parseResponse: response => {. "message": array(string)} = "parse";

let send = (~responseCB, ~errorCB, ~apiURL) => {
    let request = makeXMLHttpRequest()

    request->addEventListener("load", ()  => responseCB( (request->response->parseResponse)##message ) )
    request->addEventListener("error", () => errorCB())
    request->open_("GET", apiURL)

    request->send
    /* How do I return the "request->abort" method as an option? */
    /* Some(request->abort) */
    None
}
```

I invoke the above with:

```
let responseCB = (response) => setState(_previousState => LoadedDogs(response));
let errorCB = () => setState(_previousState => ErrorFetchingDogs);

React.useEffect0(
    () => XMLHttpRequest.send(
            ~responseCB,
            ~errorCB,
            ~apiURL="https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/3"
        )
);
```

I'm *very* new to FP having been a C jocky for 30+ years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, since you're not saying what error you get if you try doing "the obvious", the problem is that `React.useEffect0` expects an `option(unit => unit)` while `Some(request->abort)` would execute `request->abort` immediately and return `option(unit)`.

If so, the solution should just be to create a `unit => unit` function that simply calls `request->abort` when invoked:

```ml
Some(() => request->abort)
```